# Cannot click div when it overlays clickable d3 elements

Tags: css, events, angularjs, onclick, d3.js

I have made a d3 map with an overlaying non-d3 div with information. The content of the overlaying div is not clickable despite having a higher z-index.

The bits of code defining the z-index and other properties of the map and overlaying div are provided below:

**Main Page HTML Template:**

```
<button ng-click="getLocation()">Find District by Current Location</button>
<input class="zip_field" ng-model="selected_zip"></input>
<button ng-click="findDistrictByZip()">Find District by Zip Code</button>
{{warning}}
<div id="map_holder"> </div>
<div id="map_dialog"> </div>
```

**#map_dialog HTML sub-template:**

```
<h4>District {{state_district.state}}-{{state_district.district}}</h4>
<button ng-click="testFunc()">This Button Does Nothing</button>
<div ng-repeat="rep in district_reps">
    <div class="controls-row">
        <h5>{{rep.title}}. {{rep.first_name}} {{rep.last_name}}</h5>
    </div>
```

**#map_holder (underlying element) definitions in Angular Controller:**

```
      svg = d3.select("#map_holder").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
      $scope.usMap = svg.append("g").attr("id", "map_with_districts")
$scope.usMap.append("defs").append("path").attr("id", "land").datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land)).attr "d", path
        $scope.usMap.append("clipPath").attr("id", "clip-land").append("use").attr "xlink:href", "#land"
        district = $scope.usMap.append("g").attr("class", "districts").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)").selectAll("path").data(topojson.feature(congress, congress.objects.districts).features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).text (d) ->
          "#{$scope.FIPS_to_state[d.id / 100 | 0]}-#{d.id % 100}"
        district.on("mouseover", () ->
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(d3.select(this).text())
        ).on("mousemove", () -> 
          return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-27)+"px").style("left", (event.pageX+"px"))
        ).on("mouseout", () -> 
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")
        ).on("click", () ->
          district_id = d3.select(this).text()
          $scope.state_district = {state: district_id.slice(0, 2), district: district_id.slice(3, 6)}
          $scope.$apply()
        )
        $scope.usMap.append("path").attr("class", "district-boundaries").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)").datum(topojson.mesh(congress, congress.objects.districts, (a, b) ->
          (a.id / 1000 | 0) is (b.id / 1000 | 0)
        )).attr "d", path
        $scope.usMap.append("path").attr("class", "state-boundaries").datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, (a, b) ->
          a isnt b
        )).attr "d", path
        $('#map_holder').on("dblclick", () ->
          $scope.zoomOut()
        )
```

**#map_dialog (overlaying element) definitions in Angular Controller:**

```
// initialize as hidden
dialog = d3.select("#map_dialog")
        .style("opacity", 1e-6)
        .style("z-index", "1000")
// method toggling visibility
    $scope.showDistrictDialog = () ->
      $('#map_dialog').html($compile("<sub-view template='partial/district_reps'></sub-view>")($scope)) 
      d3.select('#map_dialog')
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("opacity", 1)
```

**CSS properties:**
  I've tinkered with these extensively, usually setting the overlaying div's position to absolute. I've tried various z-indexes and other positioning. I've also tried nesting the dom elements in different ways.

I've tried calling stopPropogation in my event handlers, I've messed around with pointer-event:none, pointer-event:visible, etc, but these courses of actions either disable map events completely or have no effect.

Putting a click handler on $('body') that prints out the event target similarly shows that clicks on this div are registered as clicks on the underlying map.

The I took **[this screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/vvg32s86v/)** below while trying to click the button in the overlaying div (sorry my cursor was not in the screenshot). Upon clicking over the button d3 state object below is highlighted and the button is not being activated. It doesn't even depress the button or notice the click at all.

Comment: Long shot, but have you tried setting `z-index` as an `attr` instead of as a `style`?

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try; it sets z-index as a property but this does not fix the problem, the div is still un-selectable. Thank you for replying though, appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the `z-index` on the other element (i.e. the one supposed to be below)?

Comment: Yes, I've set the z-index on both the element that should be below and the overlaying element, always making sure that the element below has a lower z-index. I've set this both through the d3 .attr and .style methods, and in my CSS definition. Oddly this problem is not fixed by setting z-index. Thanks again for the advice though!

Comment: Don't forget that `z-index` only affects elements with `position` values other than the default `static`. Also keep in mind that the `z-index` property is only relative to the closest parent with `position` values other than `static`. Lastly, a quick and easy way to check stacking order is to use the "Inspect Element" of the webkit Developer Tools. If you right-click to "Inspect Element" of the `<button>` and a different element is selected for you to inspect instead, then you know that the stacking order is not correct. Fiddle with the property values and then do another right-click.

Comment: Do you have a test page we can examine?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have used inspector and the map layer appears to overlay the dialog -- it is unselectable unless I go through the elements view. Even when calling d3's order and sort methods to shift the underlying map layer to the lowest level (it becomes invisible) using inspector will still select that layer before selecting the overlaying information window.

I plan to have this site hosted soon and will post here when it's up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the problem above occurred because the element that was supposed to overlay the map, which was rendered as a sub-template with Angular, was instantiated and modified using D3 methods. The problem was fixed by taking the content of this sub-template and putting it in the same HTML file as the map it is overlaying, and then toggling hide/show for that content.